# Converting the key variable Case to Camel Case using Jolt

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt, camelcasing

I am getting data from the database sources in the following format with capital keys.
I want to convert keys in camel case using the `JOLT` transformation.

json which I may be getting does not contains fixed key value pairs. Key can vary case-to-case basis

**input json**

```json
[
  {
    "LAST_UPDT_TS": "2018-05-21 07:52:06.0",
    "RTRV_TS": "2023-02-08 06:03:03.932108",
    "DOC_ID": "1-102GJ8CY",
    "PARENT_ASSET_DOC_ID": null,
    "ASSET_STATUS": "Inactive",
    "CAGE_NUM": "SUBZ6G"
  },
  {
    "LAST_UPDT_TS": "2020-09-09 22:28:25.0",
    "RTRV_TS": "2023-02-08 06:03:03.932108",
    "DOC_ID": "1-102MDPE7",
    "PARENT_ASSET_DOC_ID": null,
    "ASSET_STATUS": "Active",
    "CAGE_NUM": "012210"
  }
]
```

**Expected output**

```json
[
  {
    "lastUpdtTs": "2018-05-21 07:52:06.0",
    "rtrvTs": "2023-02-08 06:03:03.932108",
    "docId": "1-102GJ8CY",
    "ParentAssetDocId": null,
    "AssetStatus": "Inactive",
    "CageNum": "SUBZ6G"
  },
  {
    "lastUpdtTs": "2020-09-09 22:28:25.0",
    "retrieveTimestamp": "2023-02-08 06:03:03.932108",
    "docId": "1-102MDPE7",
    "ParentAssetDocId": null,
    "AssetStatus": "Active",
    "CageNum": "012210"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following spec

```json
[// Preparation for the next spec for assigning default "null" for null values of which the attributes won't vanish
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "null"
      }
    }
  },
  {// Exchange key-value pairs
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2.&1.@(0)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// Split values by underscores in order to convert them to independent arrays for each attribute
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=split('_',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// Convert all values to lowercase letters
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "=toLower"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// Enumerate each components of the arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&3.&2.&1.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// Split those components letterwise
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "=split('',@(1,&))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// Enumerate each components of the arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {// Convert only the first letters of the derived pieces to uppercase letters by use of 0th(zeroth) index
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "0": "=toUpper"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// Rearrange the elements to prepare to combine the pieces
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&4.&3.&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// Combine the pieces in order to get new values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {// Make values keys, while keys to values
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "[&3].@(0)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {// get back again the real null values
        "*": {
          "null": "[&2].&1",
          "*": {
            "@1": "[&3].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

There are two immediate handicaps :

1. Disappearing **null** values during key-value exchange. Used the first and the last specs to handle this issue.
2. Identical values which would prevent separation of keys after applied key-value exchange. An extra level of deepness added to specs in order to handle this.